# applying styling to only one element of a class

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles

I have 3 h1 tags. For example:

```
<div class="headline">
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<h1>heading 2</h1>
<h1>heading 3</h1>
</div>
```

I want to add padding-bottom to only the last headline tag in this block. the headlines are filled from an array, so it can have any number of headlines

I tried
`.headline:last-child { padding-bottom: 10px;`
but it didnt work

Comment: adding a class to element you want to change and then applying any rules on that class is a better approach

Comment: @Coolis the headlines are filled from an array, so it can have any number of headlines

Comment: That information changes the question. Just updated my answer if you want to have a look. Hope that helps.

Comment: You want `.headline h1:last-of-type` or `.headline h1:last-child` - this has been asked so many times.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .heading h1:last-child{
            background-color: rgb(18, 18, 175);
            color: gainsboro;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>first heading</h1>
        <h1>second heading</h1>
        <h1>third heading</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about providing some information along with your code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `last-of-type` to do this. You can read more about `last-of-type` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).

Below is an example of selecting the last element in a list of elements, no matter how long that list is.

Edit: `last-of-type` ensures you're only targetting the `h1`. If you use `last-child`, a `p` tag in the array will be styled, not just headings. If that is what you want, you can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child#:%7E:text=The%20%3Alast%2Dchild%20CSS%20pseudo,a%20group%20of%20sibling%20elements.). IF you do want to use `last-child` specifically, simply replace the `last-of-type` selector in my example below with it and it will work.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/Kxrl/pen/wvXLaLm)

```css
.headline h1 {
  color: red;
}

.headline h1:last-of-type {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h1>Heading 2</h1>
  <h1>Heading 3</h1>
  <h1>Heading 4</h1>
  <h1>Heading 5</h1>
</div>
```